# About 2PL transaction, How can I arrange the following transaction without deadlock

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions

My purpose is to display concurrent processing when the database transactions T1, T2, and T3 interleave their operations in the same way as above and the concurrent processing is controlled by a scheduler implementing 2PL protocol. The following figure is about the question. And my own solution is in the second figure. But it seems to have a deadlock. How can I solve it by 2PL without deadlock...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HKX4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiOFu.png)